# Setting UITabBarItem image in storyboard but different looking after run app

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

1) i add four png image in Assets.xcassets.
[image: selected image]

[image: normal image]

2)In storyboard, i embed in a Tab Bar Controller. Setting TabBarItem image.
[image: storyboard setting]

3) But after running app. I found the image look seems a little different with my setting and i don't known why, can anyone know why and how to fixed? Waiting for you help,thanks
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why the image looks different is because it is being filled with plane colour, while your .png contains some white instead of empty background. `UIImage` has a property called `renderingMode`. This property can be `default`, `AlwaysOrigin`, `AlwaysTemplate`.

So for `UITabBarItem` the default rendering mode is `AlwaysTemplate`, that is why your image is being filled. And since your image contains a white background inside the search icon (where it should have contained no drawing) it gets also filled.

So you have two options:
 1. Remove the white background from the icon.
 2. Since you are using XCAssets, you can change the rendering mode in XCAssets attributes pane.

Here is where you can do that from XCAssets:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need set UIImage.renderingMode,
try this

```
NSArray *items = self.tabBar.items;
UITabBarItem *item = items[0];
item.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_recruit.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```